# Extract uppercase words till the first lowercase letter

Tags: r, regex

I need to extract the first part of a text, which is uppercase till the first letter lowercase.

For example, I have the text: "IV LONG TEXT HERE and now the Text End HERE"

I want to extract the "IV LONG TEXT HERE".

I have been trying something like this:

```r
text <- "IV LONG TEXT HERE and now the Text End HERE"

stringr::str_extract_all(text, "[A-Z]")
```

but I'm failing at the regex.

Comment: You may need `stringr::str_replace(text, "([A-Z ]+)\\s+.*", "\\1")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use str_extract, with a pattern to match a single uppercase char and optionally match spaces and uppercase chars ending with another uppercase char.

```
\b[A-Z](?:[A-Z ]*[A-Z])?\b
```

**Explanation**

- `\b[A-Z]` A word boundary to prevent a partial word match, then match a single char A-Z
- `(?:` Non capture group to match as a whole

  - `[A-Z ]*[A-Z]` Match optional chars A-Z or a space and match a char A-Z
- `)?` Close the non capture group and make it optional
- `\b` A word boundary

Example

```
text <- "IV LONG TEXT HERE and now the Text End HERE"

stringr::str_extract(text, "\\b[A-Z](?:[A-Z ]*[A-Z])?\\b")
```

Output

```
[1] "IV LONG TEXT HERE"
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `str_extract` use `str_replace` or `str_remove`

```
library(stringr)
# match one or more space (\\s+) followed by
# one or more lower case letters ([a-z]+) and rest of the characters (.*)
# to remove those matched characters
str_remove(text, "\\s+[a-z]+.*")
[1] "IV LONG TEXT HERE"
# or match one or more upper case letters including spaces ([A-Z ]+)
# capture as group `()` followed one or more space (\\s+) and rest of
#characters (.*), replace with the backreference (\\1) of captured group
str_replace(text, "([A-Z ]+)\\s+.*", "\\1")
[1] "IV LONG TEXT HERE"
```

Answer (score 1):

The below code sample should work.

```
text <- "IV LONG TEXT HERE and now the Text End HERE"

stringr::str_extract_all(text, "\\w.*[A-Z] \\b")
```

**Output :**

```
[1] 'IV LONG TEXT HERE '
```

**Interpretation :**

Return any word character **(\w)** that appears zero times or more **(.*)** , satisfies the uppercase **([A-Z])** range and ends up with space **( \b)**.