# How to extract the first uppercase words and numbers from a vehicle model and derivative string?

Tags: php, regex

I currently get a list of vehicles from a 3rd party, but it is all a single long string.
I used RegEx to split based on the engine size (e.g. 1.2, 120kW, etc), but this only works for certain car brands.
Others will use a different format for their vehicle naming.

I have since noticed that the Model of the vehicle is always in UPPERCASE at the beginning of the string. The remainder is the derivative of the vehicle (e.g. the engine, spec, doors etc).

Here are some examples of strings. I have added a line '**|**' where it needs splitting (the line isn't there in the actual string):

> XC40 DIESEL ESTATE **|** 2.0 D4 [190] Inscription Pro 5dr AWD Gea+
>
> RAPID DIESEL HATCHBACK **|** 1.6 TDI CR Elegance 5dr
>
> ID.4 ESTATE **|** 109kW City Pure 52kWh 5dr Auto V40 DIESEL HATCHBACK D2 [120] Momentum 5dr Geartronic
>
> HILUX SPECIAL EDITIONS **|** Invincible X Ltd Ed D/Cab P/Up 2.4 D+
>
> A CLASS DIESEL HATCHBACK **|** A180d Sport Executive 5dr Auto X3 ESTATE xDrive M40i 5dr Auto

The following overflow question answers 90% of my question, but it only focuses on Full uppercase words and ignores numbers and decimals, which causes issues with eg the ID.4 and XC40. ([Extract uppercase words till the first lowercase letter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72280265/extract-uppercase-words-till-the-first-lowercase-letter))

The RegEx which the above post mentions is: `\b[A-Z]([A-Z ]*[A-Z])?\b` It works great apart from the numbers being excluded

Here is a link to the active regexr.com I am working on. It has a few test strings to test against: https://regexr.com/6tur8

The goal is to convert (eg):
This:

> XC40 DIESEL ESTATE 2.0 D4 [190] Inscription Pro 5dr AWD Gea+

To This:

> Model: XC40 DIESEL ESTATE
>
> Derivative: 2.0 D4 [190] Inscription Pro 5dr AWD Gea+ Currently it is not identifying the XC40 part.

As you can see in the regexr link, vehicles come in all variations, with one thing in common; the Model is always in UPPERCASE at the beginning of the string.

I am working in PHP to split the string using preg_split, and I presume that RegEx is the best solution for this?

Comment: Perhaps like this `^[A-Z](?:[A-Z0-9. ]*[A-Z])?\b` https://regex101.com/r/OP2TYz/1

Comment: is there a model like `XC40 DIESEL ESTATE XC40`? then it won't end in an uppercase letter and the last `XC40` would not get matched.

Comment: Much much closer, but the 2 Series Coupe doesn't match. I presume as it is a single digit. and the Model 3 also does not match the number. It almost needs to match single digits if it is nested between uppercase words. Although that would still not match the TESLA MODEL 3

Comment: Then you might write it like this `^[A-Z0-9](?:[A-Z0-9. ]*[A-Z0-9])?\b` https://regex101.com/r/87jTGA/1

Comment: What if Tesla creates a new model called `TESLA MODEL 3.0`? Then we would have a clash between the `RAPID DIESEL HATCHBACK | 1.6 ` not wanting to take the `1.6` but the Tesla model wanting to take the `3.0` -> maybe RegEx is not the best choice here, since the rules are not 100% clear

Comment: I think it can be assumed that any part with a digit would not have a decimal, or go over 2 numbers. Eg. XC40 or C3 or 3. Anything with more than 2 numbers or a decimal is most likely part of the derivative. If there is one that matches eg M40i, it shouldn't match anyways as it is after a lowercase word

Comment: @Thefourthbird, in that instance, it matches the 2.0 D4 in: XC40 DIESEL ESTATE 2.0 D4 [190] Inscription Pro 5dr AWD Gea+

Comment: @OnnoRouast, I wouldn't put it past Elon to do something like that... What would you suggest is a better option? Apart from having a DB and trying to match a vehicle string to a record in the DB.
Although... if this regex can be 99% accurate (ignoring the possibility of a Model 3.0), then I think I would be quite happy with that

Comment: @MaxR If you could get a list/DB with all available models then you can match against that!

Comment: @OnnoRouast if only getting an up-to-date and 100% accurate list of manufacturers and models was that easy  Would have saved countless headaches!

Comment: @MaxR Yes there can be many variations for the models. You can tweak it a bit excluding digits with a dot like `^[A-Z0-9](?:(?!\d+\.\d)[A-Z0-9. ])*(?!\S)` https://regex101.com/r/3Qg6J1/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird that is now 99% there. Only anomaly is this: 
V40 DIESEL HATCHBACK D2 [120] Momentum 5dr Geartronic
It is including the D2 part.
And: C CLASS DIESEL SALOON C250 BlueTEC SE 4dr Auto
Is including the C250 part

Comment: `^( ?(\d|([A-Z0-9\.]*[A-Z][A-Z0-9\.]*))(?= ))*`  ?  https://regex101.com/r/xGEH3a/1

Comment: Yes and that is the hardest part, how can you tell that D2 is not part of the model? `^[A-Z0-9](?:(?!\d+\.\d)[A-Z0-9. ])*(?!\S)(?!\s*\[\d+])` https://regex101.com/r/1OLQfe/1

Comment: seems like a good strategy, make a set of "break words" like that and then take all the string up to it

Comment: Maybe the last match can only be LETTERS and maybe 3+ characters?
It would then stop at HATCHBACK, ESTATE, SALOON, EDITIONS, SUV, etc and not process anything after that?
I am hopeless at regex as you can tell 

Comment: @OnnoRouast I redacted that, as this is only a handful of vehicle examples. Keeping an up-to-date list of 'break words' is near impossible.
Eg: HILUX SPECIAL EDITIONS Invincible X Ltd Ed D/Cab P/Up 2.4 D+
Would have to add EDITIONS, but some vehicles might have another word after that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a result of the discussion in the comments (getting a list of models would be the best option, but is impossible) my best try is this:

```
^((\d|([A-Z0-9\.]*[A-Z][A-Z0-9\.]*)) )*([A-Z]{3,})
```

It has to end in an uppercase-only word with at least 3 letters `([A-Z]{3,})` and before that matches any number of times either a single digit `\d` or any word that contains at least one uppercase letter `[A-Z]` and any number of these characters before or after the uppercase letter `[A-Z0-9\.]`.

https://regex101.com/r/35fILx/1

It will probably need a lot of updating for edge-cases in the other models! In the worst case you can use this regex for most cases, and then hand-code the bad edge cases.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to cross matching a digit-dot-digit and ending on 3 or more uppercase chars:

```
^[A-Z\d](?:(?!\d+\.\d)[A-Z\d.\h])*[A-Z]{3,}
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `[A-Z\d]` Match a single char A-Z or a digit
- `(?:` Non capture group to repeat as a whole part

  - `(?!\d+\.\d)` Assert not 1+ digits `.` and 1 digit to the right
  - `[A-Z\d.\h]` Match 1 char of the listed, where `\h` matches a horizontal whitespace char
- `)*` Close the non capture group and optionally repeat it
- `[A-Z]{3,}` Match 3 or more uppercase chars

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Oi3x7G/1).

Or written a bit more efficient without the negative lookahead:

```
^(?:\d\h+|[\d.]*[A-Z][A-Z\d.]*\h+)*[A-Z]{3,}
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `\d\h+` Match a single digit and 1+ spaces
  - `|` Or
  - `[\d.]*[A-Z][A-Z\d.]*\h+` Match at least 1 uppercase char A-Z between optional digits and dots
- `)*` Close the non capture group and optionally repeat it
- `[A-Z]{3,}` Match 3 or more uppercase chars

See another [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/T65YLW/1).